# Xcode Error When Linking

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity to develop a VR App, and I really don't know what I'm doing with X Code..I've looked at nearly every submission with the same issue, and I can't resolve it.

In X Code 8, when building my project from Unity I get this error "apple mach-o linker error linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)". I'm happy to give you any information to help, but I'm not really sure what you would need to understand the issue better.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: I've also noticed that I only get this error when X Code is "Linking", not sure if this helps.

**EDIT**: (this is where the error begins) ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/CraigSpreadbury/New/Build_1/Pods/GVRSDK/NDK/Libraries/libGVRNDK_x86.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/CraigSpreadbury/New/Build_1/Pods/GVRSDK/NDK/Libraries/libGVRNDK_x86.a (2 slices)

Comment: are you using google vr? It seems like you are doing that.

Comment: Yes it is with the Google VR SDK within Unity